# I want to pause step counter sensor in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sensors

```
   override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    try {
        Log.e("TAG", "onDestroy:::Service==>>> " )
        val sm = getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        sm.unregisterListener(this,sm.getDefaultSensor(Constant.SENSOR_TYPE))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Hello, I want to pause the step counting sensor whenever a user will press the stop button after that can't be counting steps.

But Currently in my code, I have called the onDestory method on the click stop button but still counting which means I can't pause the sensor for step counting. So can anyone answer me that is there any way to pause this case or is this not possible?

And also I have already tried to unregister the listener but still counting steps.
For example, when I pause at 500 steps and after some time try to start steps counting I'm getting some other result like 800 or 1000 steps. This is my issue.

Can anyone help me for more detail you can ask me in the comment box.

```
Val sm =
            (requireContext()).getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        val sensor = sm.getDefaultSensor(Constant.SENSOR_TYPE)
        if (sensor == null) {
            AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext()).setTitle(R.string.no_sensor)
                .setMessage(R.string.no_sensor_explain)
                .setOnDismissListener { (requireContext() as Activity).finish() }
                .setNeutralButton(
                    android.R.string.ok
                ) { dialogInterface, _ -> dialogInterface.dismiss() }
                .create().show()
        } else {
            sm.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI, 0)
        }
```

I have registred in onResume method

Comment: add your code snippet, where you're registering the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,other App is listening to StepCount sensor when you are walking

Comment: Hello
Yes, but I want to pause the step counter sensor listener so do you have any idea about it how can we pause and start at run time in the app?
Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).